# How can I request several pages without wating for the output?

Tags: python, asynchronous

I need to request a list of URLs, passing each time different variable via POST, and most importantly, I need to save the output of each request.

Is there a way with Python I can make multiple URL requests running in background so that the request are not done ones at a time (as at the moment)?

```
for exrow in exdata:
     id = exrow['increment_id']
     mage = requests.post(complete_url, data = {'id' : id})
     output = mage.content

     if output :
          f.writelines(output + ',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want are asynchronous requests. A result isn't returned immediately, but it just means it'll be handled in the background while your code can continue. At a later point, when you actually NEED the content of the request, you can retrieve it. There are several libraries built on requests that provide asynchronous calling of URLS.

- [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)
- [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures)

They both work slightly differently, but hopefully one of them will be something you can use.

I don't have personal experience with either, but they both come with [recommendations from the official requests project](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking).